# Test is not executed or not able to debug - Error : System.NotSupportedException : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

I am getting an error while running or Debug Xmarin UITest project.

The configuration on my machine is:

- Windows 7 Professional (Service Pack 1)
- Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 2015

The steps I tried to solve this error are… (After fresh installation of Windows 7 SP1)

- Updated JDK
- Double checked JDK and SDK path.
- Double Checked ANDROID_HOME path at Environment Variable.
- Updated Android SDK.
- Applied Xamarin Updates.
- Applied all available Windows 7 Updates.
- Cleaned solutions and Rebuild it.

---

```
Error / Stack Trace

Test Name:  AppLaunches
Test FullName:  ZeroChaosUITest.Tests(Android).AppLaunches
Test Source:    C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\Tests.cs : line 30
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.031

Result StackTrace:
at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Init(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Dependencies.AndroidSdkTools.BuildAndroidSdkDependencies(PotentialLocation potentialLocation)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Dependencies.AndroidSdkFinder.ResolveDependencies(PotentialLocation location)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Dependencies.AndroidSdkFinder.GetTools()
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.DefaultAndroidFactory.BuildExecutor(IProcessRunner processRunner)
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
at ZeroChaosUITest.AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform platform) in C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\AppInitializer.cs:line 26
at ZeroChaosUITest.Tests.BeforeEachTest() in C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\Tests.cs:line 25
Result Message: SetUp : System.NotSupportedException : The given path's format is not supported. .
```

Comment: Are you running this from the Command line or in Visual Studio?

Comment: Issue was regarding Windows 7.  It was reproducible even after 4 time machine format.   after installing Windows 10, it resolved automatically.